# rJava arrays conversion

Tags: arrays, rjava

i'm having troubles converting and getting types. I tried to follow the examples given in http://www.rforge.net/rJava/index.html but I wasn't able to achieve desired results.

What I want to do is to call a java method given a double array that returns an integer array.
E.g.

```java
public class SimpleDemo {

public int[] getResult(double[][] inputmatrix) {
    int[] result = new int[inputmatrix.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = i;
    }
    return(result);
}

}
```

Then in R I call

```
.jinit(classpath=<directory of the file>,force.init=T)
simple <- .jnew("SimpleDemo")
.jcall(simple,"[I","getResult",.jarray(someMatrix))
```

And what I get is

```
Error in .jcall(simple, "[I", "getResult", .jarray(someMatrix)) : 
method getResult with signature ([D)[I not found
```

My fist question is, is how I can make it work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ooookay, I found what the error was:

    .jarray(someMatrix,dispatch=T)

The dispatch argument makes sure that the matrix is treated as a 2d array. Another mistake I did, was that it is important that every entry in the matrix has type double (as.double(someMatrix) is not enough)